# can't delete cookies, nor find where are they stored

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

i am trying to learn how to handle cookies, it seems easy to understand the concept
but as i need to check what happens if i try and read non existing one 
i could not find the cookie

i have done all these :

1. deleted temporery asp.net files
2. deleted cookies in ie9
3. deleted the project and loaded via open - website.

class instance

```
public KwPosCookies.meta KwCookMet = new KwPosCookies.meta();
```

pageLoad.. : after the cookie was set i commented the creation of cookie.

```
    string getCookieDtail = "";
    //var x = KwCookMet.SetUsrCkie1(KwCookMet.cookieSName, "currUSName", "currUSMail");
    //Response.SetCookie(x);
    getCookieDtail = KwCookMet.GetUCkie1ValAsStr(KwCookMet.cookieSName, KwCookMet.usermail);
```

this is the class for cookies

```
public class KwPosCookies
{
    public class meta
    {
        public readonly string username = "UserName";
        public readonly string usermail = "UserEmail";
        public readonly string LastTimeVisit = "LTV";
        public readonly string cookieSName = "UserInfo1";
        public HttpCookie SetUsrCkie1(string CookieName, string Uname, string UMail)
        {
            var retC = new HttpCookie(CookieName);
            retC.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            retC[username] = Uname;
            retC[usermail] = UMail;
            retC[LastTimeVisit] = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

            return retC;
        }
        public string  GetUCkie1ValAsStr(string CookieName, string KeyToGet)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[CookieName][KeyToGet];
        }

    }

}
```

still reading the cookie will show it is still there (somewhere) with same values.

Comment: Are you actually using IE 9 to do your testing? Cookies are stored per-browser, so if you're using some other browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc...) to do your testing in, you'd need to delete that browser's cookies

Comment: @JedediahHoller the whole time i was using ie9, both for set cookies then to display it reads it and then to delete it's temp files & cookies . did not try chrome  or FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code I would

1. check that the cookie key is definitely the same between request and response.
2. ensure that the browser is configured to accept cookies.
3. I would get and set the cookie in the same session i.e. use a button on the page to drop the cookie. If you are running the site through Visual Studios built in webserver rerunning the site will effectively be restarting the server. Also it could use a different port. I'm not convinced you would be able to see the dropped cookie in that circumstance

**Generally**

The way that I work out what is going on with cookies is just to watch them be created and destroyed using firefox or chrome. So in chrome with the developer toolbar (F12) go

Resources -> Cookie

[image]

and get the below screen. Honestly the best way I have found to work out what is going on.

Comment: sorry missed it. I will delete that bit of the answer

Comment: theres a difference in those  two , when i have changed to Add, then i deleted cookies it did delete the cookie , so it seems if you will add the cookie  as i did(with setCookie) you will see you can not "destroy" , though your remark is what got me to this issue of differencces between setCookie and cookies.Add

Comment: i guess that setCookies is somthing to do with the application , like a database, i will check on this, if you do have insight on this let me know(;